# Is it possible to use the Javasciprt client object model from a different web server?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Basically I would like to host an application on a different server than my SharePoint server.  Using the managed client object model I have been able to access data on my SharePoint server, but I'm confused about whether I can do this using the javascript Client object model.

If I can, where do I get the sp.js file?  Am I right in assuming that this is where functionality for the javascript client object model is contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you might be constrained by the same origin policy. It prevents JavaScript from accessing information that resides in a different domain (http://domain1.com vs. http://domain2.com, or http://site1.domain.com vs. http://site2.domain.com).

There are ways to work around this rule, but still it is an important constraint.